# How to prevent data duplication?

Tags: php, sql

I want to avoid inserting existed data called username in my database, my codes run with no error but the problem is that the data I inputted was inserted even if it was already existed in my database. please tell me what's lacks with my code.

```
if($_POST["controller"] == "add") {
        // validations here
        $result = query("SELECT * FROM tbl_employee WHERE surname ='$surname'");
        if(empty($_POST["surname"]) && (query($result)>0) ) {
            echo 'surname already taken'; die();
        }
        else {
            $age = getAge($_POST["dobMonth"], $_POST["dobDay"], $_POST["dobYear"]);
            $result = query("INSERT INTO tbl_employee (carid, surname, firstname, position, department, birthplace, sex, address, contact, codename, birthdate, age, dateAdded)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", $_POST["modelo"], $_POST["surname"], $_POST["firstname"], $_POST["position"], $_POST["department"], $_POST["birthplace"], $_POST["sex"], $_POST["address"], $_POST["contact"], $_POST["codename"], $_POST["dobYear"] . '-' . $_POST["dobMonth"] . '-' . $_POST["dobDay"], $age, date("Y-m-d"));
            if($result === false) {
                echo 'error in insert'; die();
            }
            else {
                $row = query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS employee_id");
                $id = $row[0]["employee_id"];
                redirect("employee.php?profile=" . $id); //redirect("employee.php?action=view_all");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why does `empty($_POST["surname"])` mean surname already taken? So if the form is submitted with a surname value -> sure name not taken-> still insert into database.

Comment: What values you have in `$surname` and `$_POST["firstname"]` ?

Comment: Best case is that you need to set `username` as unique key in database. query will not be executed in case of duplicate value.It will be better than checking manually.

Comment: @catcon it was originally looks like this,    if(empty($_POST["surname"])) {
    echo 'error'; die();
   }
   else {

the code above is just my experiment.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan is it okay to set two unique key in one table?

Comment: @N-Jay: no we cannot. But yes in that case, we need to define composite key (combination of two attributes/columns) and then we can make it unique key.

Answer (score 0):

try this:i hope it will help you.

```
if($result['surname']==$_POST["surname"]) {
            echo 'surname already taken'; die();
        }
        else {
            $age = getAge($_POST["dobMonth"], $_POST["dobDay"], $_POST["dobYear"]);
            $result = query("INSERT INTO tbl_employee (carid, surname, firstname, position, department, birthplace, sex, address, contact, codename, birthdate, age, dateAdded)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", $_POST["modelo"], $_POST["surname"], $_POST["firstname"], $_POST["position"], $_POST["department"], $_POST["birthplace"], $_POST["sex"], $_POST["address"], $_POST["contact"], $_POST["codename"], $_POST["dobYear"] . '-' . $_POST["dobMonth"] . '-' . $_POST["dobDay"], $age, date("Y-m-d"));
            if($result === false) {
                echo 'error in insert'; die();
            }
```

Comment: thanks man, your code runs but still recorded the existed data.

Comment: remove query and  use not        
if(!empty($_POST["surname"]) && ($result)>0 ) { }

Answer (score 0):

you need to just alter your code.I hope this will help your problem.The problem with your code is first it will check whether the surname value is empty or not if you send surname value it will make the condition false because of the "AND" Condition & your else statement will executed

```
if($_POST["controller"] == "add") {
    // validations here
    $surname=(empty($_POST["surname"])?null:$_POST["surname"]);
    $result = query("SELECT * FROM tbl_employee WHERE surname ='$surname'");
    if(empty($_POST["surname"]) ){
        echo 'surname is Empty'; die();
    }
    elseif((query($result)>0) ) 
    {
        echo 'surname already taken'; die();
    }
    else {
        $age = getAge($_POST["dobMonth"], $_POST["dobDay"], $_POST["dobYear"]);
        $result = query("INSERT INTO tbl_employee (carid, surname, firstname, position, department, birthplace, sex, address, contact, codename, birthdate, age, dateAdded)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", $_POST["modelo"], $_POST["surname"], $_POST["firstname"], $_POST["position"], $_POST["department"], $_POST["birthplace"], $_POST["sex"], $_POST["address"], $_POST["contact"], $_POST["codename"], $_POST["dobYear"] . '-' . $_POST["dobMonth"] . '-' . $_POST["dobDay"], $age, date("Y-m-d"));
        if($result === false) {
            echo 'error in insert'; die();
        }
        else {
            $row = query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS employee_id");
            $id = $row[0]["employee_id"];
            redirect("employee.php?profile=" . $id); //redirect("employee.php?action=view_all");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for you codes, but it gives me an error called "Undefined variable: surname"

Comment: You are weolcome

Comment: What is the Error?

Comment: after I press the button to save, its says "Warning: PDO::prepare() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check if it's **NULL** first, before checking empty

Comment: its NO in my database, but in my form it is required

Comment: add **!**
 `if(!empty($_POST["surname"]) && (query($result)>0) ) {`